# In TikZ, is it possible to nest matrices?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

This is similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/in-tikz-is-it-possible-to-nest-nodes), but not quite the same thing. I want to make a matrix of graphs that are all relatively the same, and I made the graphs using the matrix construct.

[By the way, did you know that if you type in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> when you're writing your question, stackexchange will put a hyperlink reference for you?  Super cool.]

Comment: Re: Ctrl+L. There's a tooltip that appears above the link button that displays that information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible. When you try it, there is even an error message, that says so explicitly.