# Double nested nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-matrix, tikz-node

I want to make something like the following image in tikz:

[image: sketch]

To be able to do this, I would need to, essentially double nest nodes. I saw this post about nesting nodes: [Nested TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7814/nested-tikz-nodes).
The solution in that post uses matrices, which, according to: [In TikZ, is it possible to nest matrices?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3207/in-tikz-is-it-possible-to-nest-matrices) is not possible. Also, there is the arrows, not sure where to even start with that, that is probably gonna depend on the implementation of the double nested nodes I guess.

So, I was wondering if it is possible to create that image, or something similar through tikz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't nest nodes, rather use backgrounds and have a look at the `fit` library (which has already been mentioned in one of the linked answers):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds, positioning}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        draw,
        inner sep=10pt,
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
    \pgfsetlayers{background layer,main}

    \node (one) {Text};
    \node[below=.5cm of one] (two) {Text};
    \node[below=.5cm of two] (three) {Text};

    \node[above=.5cm of one, draw=none] (four) {Text};

    \node[fit={(three) (one)}] (wrap three) {};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
        \node[fit={(wrap three) (four)}, fill=blue!25] (wrap four) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]