# Nested TikZ nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

[This isn’t the first time this question was asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1003/42) but the other solutions don’t work in my case.

Consider the following image:

[image: screenshot]

It was created using this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=7mm,
  title/.style={font=\fontsize{6}{6}\color{black!50}\ttfamily},
  typetag/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, font=\scriptsize\ttfamily}
]
  \node (decomp) [title] { Decomposition };
  \draw [draw=black!50] (decomp.north west) rectangle +(2.8cm, -2.7cm);

  \node (di) [typetag, below=of decomp.west, anchor=west, xshift=2mm] { Independent };
  \node (dr) [typetag, below=of di.west, anchor=west] { Reduction };
  \node (dnc) [typetag, below=of dr.west, anchor=west] { DivideAndConquer };

  \node (dep) at (3cm, 0) [title] { Dependency };
  \draw [draw=black!50] (dep.north west) rectangle ($(dep.north east) - (0, 2cm)$);

  \node (da) [typetag, below=of dep.west, anchor=west, xshift=2mm] { Atomic };
  \node (dr) [typetag, below=of da.west, anchor=west] { Range };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Needless to say, this code is horribly complicated and has no automation (for example, the width of the borders isn’t auto-computed to fit all elements, but rather put in by hand via painstaking trial and error).

There *must* be an easier way to achieve this.

In particular, I have two questions:

1. How do I automate the drawing of the border + title (the grey text) so that the border is just large enough to accomodate all the `typetag` elements that follow after (and how to specify them?)
2. How can I arrange the `typetag` elements more smartly? (having to write, every time, `below=of Element.west, anchor=west` is *extremely* annoying, but I don’t succeed to put this into the `typetag/.style` because TikZ “forgets” this information (I have also tried adding `ever node/.style={anchor=west}` in the `tikzpicture` options, to no avail).

Question 1 is the important thing here, though. Question 2 is more of a general question that crops up again and again …

Comment: do you really need nodes? Because it is a simple combination of boxes which can be done easily with default LaTeX commands.

Comment: @Herbert: It’s part of a larger (TikZ) picture. So yes, TikZ would be much preferred, unless your solution mixes well with TikZ code (i.e. can be used *inside* TikZ).

Answer (score 32):

For the first point, you can use the `fit` library.

For the second: According to the manual, setting `below` also sets `anchor=north`. So adding `anchor=west` to `typetag` and then setting `typetag` after `below` does the trick.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=7mm,
  title/.style={font=\fontsize{6}{6}\color{black!50}\ttfamily},
  typetag/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, font=\scriptsize\ttfamily, anchor=west}
]
  \node (decomp) [title] { Decomposition };

  \node (di) [below=of decomp.west, typetag, xshift=2mm] { Independent };
  \node (dr) [below=of di.west, typetag] { Reduction };
  \node (dnc) [below=of dr.west, typetag] { DivideAndConquer };

  \node [draw=black!50, fit={(decomp) (di) (dr) (dnc)}] {};

  \node (dep) at (3cm, 0) [title] { Dependency };

  \node (da) [below=of dep.west, typetag, xshift=2mm] { Atomic };
  \node (dr) [below=of da.west, typetag] { Range };

  \node [draw=black!50, fit={(dep) (dr) (da)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(`inner sep`, should probably be adjusted a bit)

Answer (score 10):

Would a `matrix` make sense here? ie:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily,
  mymatrix/.style={matrix of nodes, nodes=typetag, row sep=1em},
  mycontainer/.style={draw=gray, inner sep=1ex},
  typetag/.style={draw=gray, inner sep=1ex, anchor=west},
  title/.style={draw=none, color=gray, inner sep=0pt}
  ]
  \matrix[mymatrix] (mx1) {
    |[title]|Decomposition \\
    Independent \\
    Reduction \\
    DivideAndConquer \\
  };
  \matrix[mymatrix, right=of mx1.north east, matrix anchor=north west] (mx2) {
    |[title]|Dependency \\
    Atomic \\
    Range \\
  };
  \node[mycontainer, fit=(mx1)] {};
  \node[mycontainer, fit=(mx2)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the example]

Comment: Interesting approach. Perhaps this could work. However, is there a way to make the top and left margins of the `title` attributes *much* smaller than the rest? These two entries should effectively be glued to the frame, and be very small. Perhaps using `shift`? I’ll try it some time.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I always feel dirty for some reason when shifting. Also, it didn't seem to work here. Instead, you could try adding `inner sep=-1ex` to `title`'s style. If you'd like, I could update those to my answer aswell.

Comment: May be you can write Decomposition and Dependency with a label of the container nodes instead of being matrix nodes.

Comment: @Ignasi: I actually tried that. It would require shifting the label, as well as the container contents (with `\\\`'s for example), which seemed rather icky. Also, I'm not sure how you could left-align the title, then.

Comment: Look at my answer. I used a \phantom to reserve some place inside the matrix and a new node for the title.

Comment: The problem with tikzmatrices is that you cannot nest them if needed

Answer (score 3):

Here it is the same with only `\fbox` and automatic calculation of the box sizes can also be used inside of tikz. If you need connections, you can set single nodes of the box contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
  
\begin{document}

\fboxsep=10pt\sffamily\setstretch{2}
\fbox{\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
\tikzset{node distance=7mm,
  title/.style={font=\color{black!50}\ttfamily},
  typetag/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, font=\large\ttfamily}}

\fboxsep=10pt\sffamily\setstretch{2}
\fbox{\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
\tikz\node (decomp) [title] { Decomposition };

\tikz\node (di) [typetag]{ Independent };

\tikz\node (dr) [typetag]{ Reduction\vphantom{g} };

\tikz\node (dnc) [typetag]{ DivideAndConquer};

\end{varwidth}}\qquad
\fbox{\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
\tikz\node (dep) [title] { Dependency };

\fbox{\bfseries Atomic}

\fbox{\bfseries Range}
\end{varwidth}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: dang, I oversimplified. I’m so, so sorry. :-( The inner boxes in my code are actually more complex (custom TikZ) shapes, not rectangles.

Comment: @Konrad: I cannot see a problem here, because all inner rectangles can be single nodes with any shape instead of the fbox

Comment: I edited the code so that you can see what I mean

Comment: I can’t get this to work … when I replace the inner fboxes by notes, chaos ensues. In particular, the `varwidth` box doesn’t seem to heed the nodes in its width calculation and the height is only approximately right.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have another option with matrix. You can 'draw' the matrix node, so don't need to use a fitting node. I could not declare titles with label (may be someone knows how to do it) but with another node anchored to matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, fit}

\usepackage[active,tightpage,pdftex]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily,
  mymatrix/.style={matrix of nodes, nodes=typetag, row sep=1em},
  mycontainer/.style={draw=gray, inner sep=1ex},
  typetag/.style={draw=gray, inner sep=1ex, anchor=west},
  title/.style={draw=none, color=gray, inner sep=0pt,font=\ttfamily\footnotesize}
  ]
  \matrix[mymatrix,draw] (mx1) {
    |[title]|\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaa} \\
    Independent \\
    Reduction \\
    DivideAndConquer \\
  };
  \matrix[mymatrix, right=of mx1.north east, matrix anchor=north west,draw] (mx2) {
    |[title]|\phantom{aaaaaaaaa} \\
    Atomic \\
    Range \\
  };
  \node[title,anchor=north west,outer sep=2pt] () at (mx1.north west) {Decomposition};
  \node[title,anchor=north west,outer sep=2pt] () at (mx2.north west) {Dependency};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here you have the result:

[image]