# How to nest a graph within a node in TikZ and draw edges between the graphs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, nesting

I'm trying to draw a graph and have a separate graph within one of the outer nodes. I seen this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/in-tikz-is-it-possible-to-nest-nodes), but I don't understand how the `matrix` nodes will help me. I would also like to draw edges between the outer nodes to the inner nodes.

Could someone please make a quick example of with 3 nodes, where one of the nodes contains a subgraph with 3 nodes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a little example: two "outer" nodes, each one containing a graph (formed with "inner" nodes) and some edges and arrows connecting outer nodes to outer nodes, and inner nodes from one graph to inner nodes of the other; the `remember picture` option lets you access inner and outer nodes at any time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
  inner/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
  outer/.style={draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt}
  ]
  \node[outer,draw=green] (A) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [inner,draw=blue] (ai)  {A1};
      \node [inner,draw=blue,below=of ai] (aii) {A2};
      \node [inner,draw=blue,right=of aii] (aiii) {A3};
      \draw[red,thick] (ai) -- (aii) -- (aiii) -- (ai);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  \node[outer,draw=green,right=of A] (B) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [inner,draw=blue] (bi)  {B1};
      \node [inner,draw=blue,below=of bi] (bii) {B2};
      \node [inner,draw=blue,right=of bii] (biii) {B3};
      \node [inner,draw=blue,right=of bi] (biv) {B4};
      \draw[red,thick] (bi) -- (bii) -- (biii) -- (biv) -- (bi) -- (biii);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  \draw[thick,orange,->] (ai) -- (bii);
  \draw[orange,->] (aiii) -- (bi);
  \draw[orange,->] (A.90) -- ($(A.90)+(0,1)$) -| (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, this did it; `remember picture` was the key! Thanks!

Comment: This does work with pdflatex but not with latex--dvipdf. See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186583/34812

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the kind of problems that OP has with `TiKZ matrices` but Gonzalo's example is the kind of graph where a `matrix` is really helpful.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  inner/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
  outer/.style={draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm}
  ]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner}]{
    A1 \\
    A2 & A3\\
  };

  \matrix (B) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner}, right=of A]{
    B1 & B4\\
    B2 & B3\\
  };

  \draw[red, thick] (A-1-1)--(A-2-1)--(A-2-2)--(A-1-1);
  \draw[red, thick] (B-1-1)--(B-1-2)--(B-2-2)--(B-2-1)--(B-1-1);
  \draw[thick, orange,->] (A-1-1)--(B-2-1);
  \draw[thick, orange,->] (A-2-2)--(B-1-1);
  \draw[thick, orange,->] (A.north)--([yshift=1cm]A.north)-|(B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) answer I figured out this neat code, that is useful when one wants to duplicate graph components. It also automates indexing to some degree.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\blocknode}[1]{
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={thick, circle, draw ,minimum width=5mm}]
        \draw (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,0) -- cycle;
        \node (T#1) at (2.5, 1){T#1};
        \node (L#1) at (  1, 4){L#1};
        \node (R#1) at (  4, 4){R#1};
        \draw (L#1) to (T#1);
        \draw (R#1) to (T#1);
    \end{scope}
}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node (N1) at (0,0){\tikz{\blocknode{1}}};
    \node (N2) at (9,3){\tikz{\blocknode{2}}};
    \draw[color=red] (L1) -- (T1) --(R1) --(L1);
    \draw[color=blue] (L2) -- (T2) --(R2) --(L2);
    \draw[color=green] (L1) -- (L2) (R1)--(R2) (T1) --(T2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]