# Pointing (an arrow) to a tabular node in beamer is buggy (ignorenonframetext)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows, nodes

Maybe a bug in beamer, works OK while using the minimal document class.

Again, following [the example over there](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/), and also after playing with [Circling/framing and referring to a bunch of nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84108/circling-framing-and-referring-to-a-bunch-of-nodes),  the following doesn't work as expected:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,xcolor={table,svgnames}]{beamer}
%\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,fit,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]


\begin{frame}

  \tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Blah & $=$ Again blah 
    \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (blah) {};\\ 
    Foo & $+$ Bar \\
    Buggy & $=$
    \tikz[baseline]{
      \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (bug)
      {Bug};
    }
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

 This is also buggy, booh \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (booh) {};

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[very thick,->] (blah) edge [bend right] (bug);
    \path[very thick,->] (booh) edge [bend left] (bug);
  \end{tikzpicture}  

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**I just found the culprit, it is the ignorenonframetext option!! But why is it so?**

Comment: I just found the culprit, it is the ignorenonframetext option!! But why is it so?

Comment: It's beaceuse `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]` is outside the frame and inside the body of the document, so `ignorenonframetext` just ignores the remember picture` part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]` is outside the frame and inside the body of the document, so `ignorenonframetext` just ignores the `remember picture` part. You can send this to the preamble (to make it global) or inside the `frame` environment (notice that I used `\tikzset` instead of the obsolete `\tikzstyle`):

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,xcolor={table,svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,fit,positioning}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tikzset{na/.style={baseline=-.5ex}}

  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Blah & $=$ Again blah 
    \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (blah) {};\\ 
    Foo & $+$ Bar \\
    Buggy & $=$
    \tikz[baseline]{
      \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (bug)
      {Bug};
    }
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

 This is also buggy, booh \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (booh) {};

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[very thick,->] (blah) edge [bend right] (bug);
    \path[very thick,->] (booh) edge [bend left] (bug);
  \end{tikzpicture}  

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good!! Thanks for the explanation of the interaction of the ignorenonframetext option and the 'tikzset' location. I didn't know tikzstyle was obsolete. Point taken.