# Another TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata, memory

I got another error as below

`TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. [...ial,right= of m0] (A1B1C1) {$A_1B_1C_1$};]`

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{standalone} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paper
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{enumerate}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DRAWING PETRI NETS & DIAGRAMS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
     \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,petri,positioning,calc,fit,backgrounds,shapes.arrows,shapes.geometric,chains,matrix}
\tikzset{
    data/.style={
        ellipse,
        thick,
        draw=black,
        minimum width = 2cm,
    },
    place/.style={
        circle,
        thick,
        draw=blue,
        fill=blue!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    },
    transition/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        draw=black,
        fill=black!50,
        minimum size=6mm
    },
    transitionH/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum width=6mm,
        minimum height=2mm
    },
    transitionHW/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        draw=black,
        minimum width=6mm,
        minimum height=2mm
    },
    transitionV/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum width=2mm,
        minimum height=6mm
    },
    transitionVW/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        draw=black,
        minimum width=2mm,
        minimum height=6mm
    },
    terminal/.style={
        rounded rectangle,
        thick,
        draw=black
    },
    status/.style={
        circle,
        thick,
        draw=black,
        minimum size=15mm
    },
    decision/.style={
        diamond,
        aspect = 2,
        thick,
        draw=black
    },
    block/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        draw=black,
        minimum width = 2cm,
        rounded corners
    },
    borderE/.style={
        ellipse,
        thick,
        draw=black
    },
    borderRd/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        draw=gray,
        dashed,
        rounded corners= 5mm
    },
    %double arrow
    arrowD/.style={
        double arrow,
        fill = black,
        double arrow head extend=1mm,
        double arrow head indent =.5mm,
        minimum width=3mm,
        minimum height=7mm,
        inner ysep=0.5mm
    }
}     

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% VIETNAMESE MACROS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage[vietnam]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\begin{document}
        %if need link to inside, use ``remember picture''
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,>=stealth',bend angle=25,auto,initial text={}]
        \node [data,initial] (M0) {
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node (m0) {\begin{tabular}{c} $M_0$ \\ \_ \\ \_ \end{tabular}};
                \node [data, initial,right= of m0] (A1B1C1) {$A_1B_1C_1$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };        
    \end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

But when i remove the `initial` in `\node [data, initial,right= of m0] (A1B1C1) {$A_1B_1C_1$};` everything is okie. (see the image without the red arrow)

I want that arrow, and I dont know why it got error like that.

PS: In case you wonder about the nested `tikzpicture`, because I want to create nested node. Acording to this [nested node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27777/how-to-nest-a-graph-within-a-node-in-tikz-and-draw-edges-between-the-graphs)

[image]

Comment: Your document runs without error in texlive 2014

Comment: and only uses 48 input stack slots: ` 48i,13n,67p,407b,1225s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got that error with LaTeXTools + Sublime. I will retry on TexMaker, I am on Mac.

Comment: It seems an error in texlive 2013. I will try update and test again. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I get no error in TL 2013, but the code goes into an infinite loop with TL 2012.

Comment: Yes, it work with MacTex/TL 2014, MacTex/TL 2013 on Mac returns that error.

Comment: @thuanle Thanks, so as it's fixed with TeX Live 2014, I closed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer for the *red* arrow. (I didn't get an error as in David's comments and using pdflatex.)

The trick is setting `every initial by arrow` at the right place:

```
% preamble as in the question
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,>=stealth',bend angle=25,auto,initial text={}]
        \node [data,initial] (M0) {
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node (m0) {\begin{tabular}{c} $M_0$ \\ \_ \\ \_ \end{tabular}};
                \tikzstyle{every initial by arrow}=[red]
                \node [data,initial,right= of m0] (A1B1C1) {$A_1B_1C_1$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };        
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

or

```
\begin{document}
        %if need link to inside, use ``remember picture''
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,>=stealth',bend angle=25,auto,initial text={}]
        \node [data,initial] (M0) {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[every initial by arrow/.style=red]
                \node (m0) {\begin{tabular}{c} $M_0$ \\ \_ \\ \_ \end{tabular}};
                \node [every initial by arrow/.style=red,data,initial,right= of m0] (A1B1C1) {$A_1B_1C_1$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };        
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: thanks for answering. I am downloading the new MacTeX 2014 so will try again. But the main question is about the error. So, can't vote for your post.