# Referring to nested tikz nodes - works with pdflatex but not with latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, dvi, ps2pdf

I am trying to achieve a box within another box in tikz and then drawing an edge from the inner box to an outer node. I stumbled upon [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27789/34812)

When I compile it using pdflatex, I get the desired output(just like the answerer mentioned):

[image: Proper output]

However, compiling with latex and subsequently with dvips and ps2pdf(or dvipdf), I get this:

[image: Improper output]

I want to know what is causing this and can it be corrected, since I **need** to use latex and not pdflatex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run (latex) it twice before dvips and ps2pdf?

Comment: @Ignasi: Yes, I tried that, doesn't work!

Comment: I don't know what happens. With XeLaTeX (MikTeX updated 23/06/2014) I get same results. It's not a solution but the code in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160208/1952) works with latex+dvips+ps2pdf and xelatex.

Comment: Why do you need latex?

Comment: What do you mean by "I get same results"? Do you get the same results as me or same results with pdflatex and latex?

I need to use latex instead of pdflatex because I have to include .eps files into my document. Is there a way to convert .eps files to some other **vector graphics** format(not jpg, png or pdf) and then include them with pdflatex?

Comment: I get same results than you. And yes, you can include *.eps graphics with `epstopdf` package in preamble (which will convert them to pdf on the fly) or convert them to pdf with some conversion utility.

Comment: It works! So I don't need to use latex anymore, pdflatex will do. So my problem is solved, but the question is still valid!