# Arrows to nested nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows

I construct a TikZ image with nested nodes:[image]

As you can see, I try to add arrows from the outer node to the inner one. How is it possible to target the arrows to the correct position of the inner node (west and south)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=black, scale=1, transform shape
    , every node/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, align=center, inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=3mm}
    ]
    % change default arrow style
    \tikzset{very thick, ->, -latex, shorten <=0pt, shorten >=0pt}

    % nodes
    \node (outer) {
        Caption\\[3mm]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
            \node (inner) {Inner Text};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
    \node [above left=1mm and 10mm of inner.west] (leftabove) {left\\above};
    \node [below left=1mm and 10mm of inner.west] (leftbelow) {left\\below};

    % connections
    \draw (leftabove.east) to (outer.west);
    \draw (leftbelow.east) to (inner.west);
    \draw (leftbelow.east) to (inner.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're not nesting nodes, you're nesting tikz pictures (not advisable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alenanno explained, it's not a good idea to nest `tikzpictures`. If you want to nest nodes there are several options. One of them is shown in following code.
It uses `fit` library to define a node which contains `inner` node and its `label`. (I've declared `Caption` as `inner` label, although it could be another non drawn node).

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [mynode/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center, 
            inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=3mm},
    -latex,     
    ]

    % nodes
    \node[mynode, label={[name=lab]Caption}] (inner) {Inner text};
    \node[fit={(inner) (lab)}, draw] (outer) {};
    \node[mynode, above left=1mm and 10mm of inner.west] (leftabove) {left\\above};
    \node[mynode, below left=1mm and 10mm of inner.west] (leftbelow) {left\\below};

    % connections
    \draw (leftabove.east) to (outer.west);
    \draw (leftbelow.east) to (inner.west);
    \draw (leftbelow.east) to (inner.south);
    \draw (leftabove.east) to (lab);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I found these two helpful post by your hints: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27777/how-to-nest-a-graph-within-a-node-in-tikz-and-draw-edges-between-the-graphs and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40192/tikz-how-to-refer-to-a-node-in-nested-nodes

Answer (score 1):

like this :

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=black, scale=1, transform shape
    , every node/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, align=center, inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=3mm}
    ]
    % change default arrow style
    \tikzset{very thick, ->, -latex, shorten <=0pt, shorten >=0pt}

    % nodes
    % \node (outer) {
    %     Caption\\[3mm]
    %     \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
    %         \node (inner) {Inner Text};
    %     \end{tikzpicture}
    % };
    \node[name=outer, minimum width = 4cm, minimum height= 2cm] {};
    \node[name=caption, below=(2mm of outer.north), draw=white, inner sep=0pt] {Caption};

    \node[name=inner, above=(2mm of outer.south)] {Inner Text};

    \node [above left=1mm and 10mm of inner.west] (leftabove) {\shortstack{left\\above}};
    \node [below left=1mm and 10mm of inner.west] (leftbelow) {\shortstack{left\\below}};

    % connections
    \draw (leftabove.east) to (outer.west);
    \draw (leftbelow.east) to (inner.west);
    \draw (leftbelow.east) to (inner.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]