# Unsetting a PGF/TikZ key

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

Is there any possibility of “unsetting” a PGF/TikZ key?  By “unsetting”
I mean to remove the key from the list of keys and make PGF/TikZ behave
as if it was never specified.  To clarify, consider this minimal working
example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikz\node[draw=red, circle] {Short 1};
  \node[draw, text width=3cm] (r1) {
    \tikz\node[draw=blue, circle] {Short 2};
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the resulting output, I would expect the two circles to be of equal
size (except for a tiny difference because of “1” vs. “2”).  However,
the second (blue) circle inherits the text width property from the
parent node.  Now, I would like to have that (blue) circle behave as if
text width was never specified for it.  How do I achieve this?

What’s working, of course, is manually specifying a different text
width, but that’s not an option for me because I would like to have
*dynamic* node sizes inside another node.  Using minimum width/height on
the outer node instead of text width does not produce satisfactory
results for my eventual use-case either (which is, BTW, to have nodes of
the same size, some containing text, some containing other nodes) – I
could manage to use that, but it would mean significant overhead of
creating additional nodes, as far as I see it.

The question might, of course, be generalized into something along the lines of “How do I put a `tikzpicture` inside a TikZ node that does *not* inherit the keys set for the parent node?”

I hope to have made myself clear and that there is an easy answer to my
question ;-)

Comment: why do you write \tikz before \node?

Comment: Nesting TikZ environments like this is not supported and can lead to strange behaviour (such as what you are seeing here).  I **strongly** recommend that you find a different way to achieve what you want.  (For more on nesting, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46792/86 and the questions linked to that one)

Comment: Yes it's preferable to avoid the nesting TikZ environments ! Finally I asked bad questions ( do as I say and not as I do ) !

Comment: @Vivi: That was probably just a copy-and-paste mistake.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks for the pointer.  I didn’t know nesting pictures would cause so much trouble – so far it has worked rather well for me ;-)  It seems, though, that using a 1×1-matrix is a better way for future diagrams if I only need one level of nesting (cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/in-tikz-is-it-possible-to-nest-nodes).

Comment: @ilpssun Why not edit out the copy-and-paste mistake then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use `\tikz` inside the node you need to add `text width=` inside the blue node. If you don't do that `text width=5cm` is inherited by the last node.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw=red, circle] {Short 1}; % the first \tikz is not useful and it's a bad idea
  \node[draw, text width=5cm] (r1) {%
    \tikz \node[draw=blue, circle,text width=] {Short 2};%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the code is more complex, you need to save the included environment tikzpicture inside a box. (see the link given by Andrew)

Comment: Sneaky solution!

Comment: @AndrewStacey What do you mean by sneaky ? my dictionary gives me some strange translation. It's fine or bad ? sneaky is like snaky ? convoluted, winding, twisted, wavy, undulatory, circling, snake-like, serpentine, vermiform, vermicular, tortuous, sinuous, involved, intricate, complicated, perplexed, labyrinth, labyrinthine, peristaltic, kinky, knotted; ?? :)

Comment: This solution is actually so simple, I feel bad about asking the original question.  It works, of course, although I could have sworn I tried that to no avail before (probably, though, I just tried it with the `minimum size` key, which requires a value).

Comment: It's not so obvious. You have only one line in the manual that says : Setting ⟨dimension⟩ to an empty string causes the automatic line breaking to be disabled.

Comment: In this context, "Sneaky" is meant positively: it means I'm impressed by the solution.  Something is "sneaky" if it is unexpected.  A "sneak" (bad term) is someone who goes around quietly listening to things they oughtn't to know (Sam called Gollum a "sneak" in LOTR).  The implication is that to get this solution, you had to "sneak around" in the depths of TikZ/PGF learning things that are kept from view.  In this case, that's clearly not a bad thing to do, whence it is a term of pure praise.